# Is it a good strategy to return data list from a method (API) without ID and later bind this data list to main list by array Index ID?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, api, data-structures

I have a simple doubt.

Let me explain.

I have an employee List. The joining date info of these employees are to be got from an API.

So I select the list of EmpIds from this employee List and pass it to the API to retrieve list of date of joining.

Now, is it a good approach to return only the date List from the API without the ID, so that I can bind it to the main List using array Index. Or should I return both the id and the dates? And bind using the ID of the employee?

Comment: id is the way to go here.  The possibility for disaster is much higher when using the index rather than the id, after all that is what the id is there for.  Some collections can not guarantee order, something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no objective answer to this. You would pick the design according to your quality attributes. Are you in a performance critical environment, or do you need your answer to be self-contained. You have the two options you listed, or you could return the full employee object.

Perhaps worth thinking about is how you plan to deal with missing employees. If you query for 99 and one is missing, you can return a sparse array (partially filled with null) or you can return your id/date combo. What is more efficient if you have a million employees and you need to sort them in the exact input order (which your DB might not do just like that).

Answer (score 2):

Of Couse with the Id. Indexes are not reliable all the times. If there is some kind of an add/edit happened on the list. The index can break. If one index breaks in the middle or start of the array rest of the index ordering will be in chaos.

> A good programming pattern is to rely on Id only

Answer (score 1):

It's safier to get the Id's too, cause you can have your response in a non organized order.

Trying to get things from the index array can lead to errors, not only by order but missing values as well.

But still depends on the reliability(and also how well you know it) of the service you are consuming the data.